# How to enable download pausing for users in IE?

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, magento, firefox, download

My magento store has downloadable products for sale.

Some are very large so pause-resume function is important, however the button is greyed out on IE as in the screenshot

[image: ie]

This function works in Chrome, however in IE it causes this error and firefox is similar

My response headers:

[image]

**My question is, is there a way I can configure my products or my server to allow download pausing as standard in IE?**

*Specifics:
IE 11,
Windows8 OS,
Magento 1.8,
Downloads up to 1GB,
.rar files*

Answer (score 0):

Saw some Microsoft Support Engineer suggested these steps.

Original Post:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/pausing-a-download-using-download-manager-in/61521364-af30-41a7-a456-0d8fc8cd9f68

Comment: This would be better as a comment because it doesn't answer my question, unfortunately I've already followed these steps

Comment: I wanted to make this as a comment, but because of the technical limitation of my account I can't. I can't help myself try to help too